# Use Docker Pipeline Plugin without interactive mode

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to use docker with Jenkins Scripted pipeline, and faced with several problems.

If I use it in sh `docker ...` it results in an error

> `command not found docker`

1. I tried to fix it by changing Install setting in Global Configuration tool - but not succeed with it.
2. I'm trying to use Docker plugin now.

```
def run_my_stage(String name, String cmd, String commit) {
return {
    stage(name) {
        node("builder") {
                docker.withRegistry("192.168.1.33:5000") {
                    def myimg = docker.image("my-img")
                    sh "docker pull ${myimg.imageName()}"
                    sh "docker run ${cmd}"
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Where cmd == `--user=\$UID --rm -t -v ./build/:/home/user/build 192.168.1.33:5000/my-img`

I use this code for parallel stages (list of stages generated dynamically), and got this error

> `java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 192.168.1.33:5000`

What is proper usage of this plugin? 
I found a lot of examples with `withRun` and other methods from `docker`, but I don't need to run any commands inside this image, I have command in Dockerfile (so it built-in for my container).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error itself has the answer :).

*java.net.MalformedURLException: **no protocol**: 192.168.1.33:5000*

You are missing `protocol` in custom registry. Refer https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#custom-registry

```
def run_my_stage(String name, String cmd, String commit) {
return {
    stage(name) {
        node("builder") {
                docker.withRegistry("https://192.168.1.33:5000") {
                    def myimg = docker.image("my-img")
                    sh "docker pull ${myimg.imageName()}"
                    sh "docker run ${cmd}"
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the protocol, the registry must be `https://192.168.1.33:5000`

Answer (score 0):

Also I have problem with relative path, but simple fix with adding `pwd` before relative path to `build` fixed.

Thx @yzT